# An insolvent company still operating

Tags: germany, consumer-protection, bankruptcy

I have made an order online for a company early September, however found out the company filed for insolvency early August.

However they are still taking money from customers and never sending their orders.

I have the following questions:

- Isn’t it fraud to take money from customers even though you know you are bankrupt.
- Is there any German law that protect customers in that case?

Thank you

Comment: Not familiar with German law, but they could be reorganizing rather than winding up operations.

Comment: Whether bankrupt or not, it almost certainly would be fraud to take money for an order that they know they cannot or will not fill.  But simply being bankrupt doesn't by itself necessarily mean they can't fill it.   Other than the bankruptcy, do you have some specific reason to believe that they are not going to fill your order?

Comment: @NateEldredge They did not send me a tracking number for the shipment, I checked their instagram page, and find out many customers complaining that they are not getting the product nor the refund.

Comment: @NateEldredge I filed for chargeback and contacted the attorney responsible for administrative matters of the insolvent company, I would expect an answer by Monday.

Comment: What is the name of this supplier on your bank statement for this transaction? (Rhetorical question). They might have incorporated a new company. However if they're still using the same bank account as their old company then this could be an issue you could use to your advantage.

Comment: @DannyBeckett seems like you are right, they mentioned something about opening a new store (to the angry customers) can you please explain more? What are they trying to do here? Thank you

Comment: I am suspecting a fraud case: allowing payments yet not sending the product, and since the company is insolvent asking for a refund won’t get you anywhere…. Many customers are complaining about never receiving their orders. What can be done here? The company is still operating and from my point of view they should ban their website not to fraud other customers.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I checked their website, there IBAN is stated, however in the transaction a credit card number is present… Not sure if this information is relevant…

Comment: @Bionix1441 You need to check who you have done business with. What precise company name is on their site? E.G. ACME GmbH. What precise company name is on their Terms & Conditions? If their original company was named ACME GmbH and they became insolvent, then later they opened ACME 2 GmbH, they have probably updated their footer + T&Cs to say ACME 2 GmbH. But if you have a transaction on your bank/credit card statement to ACME GmbH (without the 2) and this occurred *after* the original company became insolvent, then it may be easier to get your money back. If it says 2 on your statement, not.